# jquery - same function for all images to fade

Tags: jquery, css

I want to apply css to image-holder when I hover on it.

Below is my css

```
#thumbholder
{
height:30%;
width:100%;
}

.imagethumb
{
height:160px;
width:200px;
border:1px solid #707070;
padding:1%;  
margin:0.6%;
}
```

Using jquery I want to get **border:1px solid #404040** border on **.imagethumb** when I place the cursor on it.
But now I get border on all images having class **.imagethumb**

Please help me to wriet a jquery function which lets individual images to get border when I place cursor on it.

Having unique id will solve this issue, but I want to try in other way. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Ismail

Comment: Do you mean `border:1px solid #707070;` or `border:1px solid #404040`?

Comment: I want to get boder:1px solid #404040 on individual images while I hover on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('.imagethumb').hover(
   function() {
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid #404040');
   },
   function() {
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid #707070');
   }
 );
```